# RestSharp body always empty

Tags: c#, .net, rest, restsharp

I need to call a Post service with RestSharp

```
 var client = new RestClient(url);
 var request = new RestRequest(url,Method.POST);
 request.AddHeader("Content-type", "application/json");
 request.AddJsonBody(new  { grant_type = "client_credentials", client_id = clientIdParam, client_secret = appReg_clientSecret, ressource = _ressource }
               ); 
 var response = client.Post(request);
```

The problem is that the request's body is always null and the json body is added as a parameter

[image]

Any ideas?

Comment: what version of RestClient are you using? Did you check under Parameters?

Comment: version:106.11.4 . it adds the body in parameters array with an extra "{=" ie {={ grant_type = client_credentials, client_id: ....}}

Comment: thats how single `{` is escaped in c#. What errors are you seeing with the execution? does it not send the json body that you are adding via `AddJsonBody`

Comment: the error is that "grant_type" is missing in the body.

Comment: I would suggest trying client.Execute(request) and see if that makes any difference

Comment: no difference the same error

Comment: We also notice the same, using version `106.11.7`.  Our requests are able to go through like this, but it would be nice to see the body populated, especially having a serialized version while debugging.

Answer (score 0):

`https://login.microsoftonline.com/{{tenantId}}/oauth2/token`
seems to not accept json, even with the content-type set as "application/json"

My solution:

```
var client = new RestClient("https://login.microsoftonline.com");
var request = new RestRequest("/{{tenantId}}/oauth2/token", Method.POST);

var requestBody = $"grant_type=client_credentials&client_id={clientIdParam}&client_secret={appReg_clientSecret}&resource={_resource}";

request.AddHeader("content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
request.AddParameter("application/x-www-form-urlencoded", requestBody, ParameterType.RequestBody);

var response = client.Execute(request);
```